# How to get the list of commands which are internally executed by Overleaf to compile a document?

Tags: compiling, overleaf

## The context

I've found [this](https://www.overleaf.com/articles/latex-more-than-just-academic-papers-and-theses/cyfvvyfrpmyn) interesting beamer presentation which lists some of the capabilities of LaTeX.

I would like to create a similar presentation, so I've downloaded the source code and now I'm trying to compile the document.

## The problem

The project comes with a `latexmkrc` file, so I've executed the following

```
$ latexmk
```

However, I'm getting some errors which make me think that I'm not executing the commands in correct order.

However, this doesn't occur with Overleaf: When opening the document, Overleaf is able to show `Compiling...` and the resulting PDF is shown. This makes me think that Overleaf is able to compile the document. For this reason, I would like to know which commands it has executed.

## The question

Is there any way to see the commands which are internally executed by Overleaf?

If that's not the case, what should I run to correctly compile the document? As explained above, `latexmk` doesn't seem to do the work.

## Additional context

Overleaf provides the following log files (see right part of the image), but, apparently, none of those files contain the commands that were executed.

[image]

Comment: What's in `latexmkrc`?

Comment: You can download the stderr and stdout files to see what latexmk is doing. (They contain the output of what latexmk is reporting to the "terminal" in Overleaf's compile server.)

Comment: At least `--enable-write-18` and `--parse-first-line` is enabled.

Comment: Oh whoops, I just realized I may have misread the question. Perhaps https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F is what you're looking for (this is the `latexmkrc` used on Overleaf if your project does not have its own). Or https://github.com/overleaf/clsi/blob/master/app/js/LatexRunner.js#L182 and following lines shows the specific command line flags used when calling latexmk in Overleaf.

Comment: Did you try compiling with LuaLaTeX? It is more robust.

Comment: Maybe some overleaf developer can just tell what command they use internally (although it's heavily dependent on which option you choose.